# Role of conducting wire in electric field production in circuits

Tags: electric-circuits

A battery creates a constant potential difference between its terminals. And when a conducting wire is connected across its terminals, the potential difference sets up an electric field within the conductor, due to which current is established in wire. But of course the electric field vanishes as soon as the conducting wire is removed, though there is still a potential difference between the terminals of the battery. That is, suppose the wire has a complex shape as given below:

[image]

The electric field lines has shape same as that of the wire when wire is connected, across the battery, but when wire is disconnected, the electric field does not retain its shape, although the potential difference across the battery does not change. So, the charges in conductor must have some role in the production of electric field. Battery plays the role of supplying the charges, but I think that the electric field in the conductor must be produced by the motion of electrons in the conductor itself, of whose mechanism I want to ask.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is, how does the conducting electrons help to create field only along the conductor, that can accelerate electrons themselves along the conductor?

Comment: The electric field is "guided" along the wire by electric charge localized on the surface of the wire. This is a subtle effect that obviously depends sensitively on the geometry of the circuit. Some discussion of this can be found for instance in J. D. Jackson, *Surface charges on circuit wires and resistors play three roles*, Am. J. Phys. 64 (1996) 855.